# Is obligation related to responsibility?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

the definition of responsibility states: "the state or fact of having a duty to deal with something or of having control over someone." we had a debate today and someone said that responsibility is related to obligation, so is it really?

Comment: To say that two abstract words about ethics are related is trivial; they're all related. The question is what the relationship is, and this is not a question about English, but about ethics.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your answer is contained in your question. The word "duty" is usually defined as a type of "obligation." (see here, for example: http://www.wordnik.com/words/duty)

Accordingly, you could replace the word "duty" in your definition of responsibility with the word "obligation" and it should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

In my business studies, I came across "obligation" in addition with liability.
I think its a stronger form as "responsible for"

Mybe you are responsible for the Project, but the company is reliable in case of compensations. An excerpt from the [Cambridge Dict.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/obligation) following:

**If you have not signed a contract, you are under no obligation to (= it is not necessary to) pay them any money.**